# IE8 CSS - background box sits on top of my text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This is how my css looks like:

```
.rounded-box{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #e4f4fd;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dedef7;
  padding: 18px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}


h3 {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

And this is how my html looks like:

```
    <div class="rounded-box">
            <h3>some text here</h3>
            <h3>some text here</h3>
    </div>
```

For some reason in IE8 (haven't tested it yet in other IEs) the rounded-box sits on top of the text. When I load the page a see for a fraction of the second my text then the rounded box covers the text.

(All the other browsers display the text as I intended on top of the rounded-box)

Any ides?

Comment: Why are you talking about "on top of" when you're text is supposed to be _inside_ the div?  Does it work when you remove the `text-shadow`?  Also posting a jsFiddle, in addition to code, would be most helpful to readers.

Comment: You apparently have not posted enough relevant code.  It's working perfectly fine in IE 8 for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/U5Ldf/

Comment: I found what caused the problem. I started to eliminate the css and js imports one by one and When I eliminated the jquery.curvycorners.min.js the problem described above went way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the solution as your answer below and mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with  jquery.curvycorners.min.js. When I eliminated it from my HTML page the problem went way.

On top of that it eliminated a problem I had in another page where I had a text field that would not show up in IE 8.